# Efficient algorithm for systems $(I + S)x = b$, where $S$ is antisymmetric?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

What is an efficient algorithm for solving linear systems $(I + S)x = b$, where $S$ is antisymmetric?

I'm hoping to hear of an algorithm that is faster than the generic algorithms for well-behaved systems.

(It is easy to show that $I + S$ is always invertible.)